# noob: How to create plugin in redmine in windows environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine-plugins

i had installed bitnami redmine stack and mysql plus ruby 1.81,and rails 2.3.11 and rubygems 1.3.7 installed in my local system.trouble is i don't know which path to go n start generating plugin even the redmine plugin tutorial polls mentioned in the wiki of redmine main site has not mentioned it.should i write ruby script/generate redmine_plugin Polls in vendor/plugin or in "C:\Program Files\BitNami Redmine Stack\apps\redmine>ruby script/generate redmine_plugin Polls -e production".need help. am also attaching the screenshots of it. also in one instance i did managed to create polls plugin trouble its not showing anywhere in folder. am attaching both screenshots here 1 [image: uresolved] 2 [image: created plugin but its not showing anywhere]

Answer (score 0):

Ok realized where i had made the mistake. apparently the database name was not common in production as well as in development in the database.yml file. Once thats corrected it started working.

Answer (score 0):

With BitNami I used the following command and it worked. First you need to find the directory where rails is stored:

```
ruby htdocs/script/rails generate redmine_plugin Polls
```